# Android show single item from a list in next page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am new to android and developing a mail like application. In the application, from a JSON string from server creating a list ( creating rows in a table view, which is embedded in a scroll view ). Now I am trying to show a single item in detail on clicking an item.

On click, getting the id of the corresponding item and load new page using the following page. My code looks like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("id", 124); 
b.putInt("message", "Message");
intent.putExtras(b); 
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

But my problem is the listing page get cleared on return back from that page.

ie, on click delete button in the child page, I want to delete the same item in the list page also. But after I deleted the item from the child page, using this code to redirect to the parent page.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("id", 124); 
intent.putExtras(b); 
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

How to delete the single item with out page refresh if coming from the child view and load the fresh page if coming directly.

Thank you for your time
Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well you just remove the desired item from the list using the `remove()` method of your `ArrayAdapter`.

A possible way to do that would be:

```
Object toRemove = arrayAdapter.getItem([POSITION]);
arrayAdapter.remove(toRemove);
```

Another way would be to modify the `ArrayList` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the ArrayAdapter.

```
arrayList.remove([INDEX]);
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another option you can use singleton class object .
Just declare a list in singleton class and use it wherever you want like following example it will be updated for everyplace

```
    public class Singleton {

       private static Singleton instance;
       private static List<Product> itemInfos = new ArrayList<Product>();
       Singleton() {
     } 

     }
```

when you comming to back activity just notify the adapter in onResume()